# can't update user password on Mongodb 4.0.5 (Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested passwords)

Tags: mongodb, authentication, password, mongodb-4.0

I'm trying to update a password from a user, using `changeUserPassword()`, and I just receive the following message:

> Error: Updating user failed: Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested passwords

```
> db
mydb
> db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id"  : "mydb.mongo",
        "user" : "mongo",
        "db"   : "mydb",
        "roles" : [
            {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "mydb"
            }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
            "SCRAM-SHA-1",
            "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
    }
]


 > db.changeUserPassword("mongo", "mongo_n3w_p4ss");
2019-05-22T20:58:10.128-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Updating user failed: Use of SCRAM-SHA-256 requires undigested passwords :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.updateUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1487:15
DB.prototype.changeUserPassword@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1491:9
@(shell):1:1
> db.version()
4.0.5
```

I also tried [updateUser()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/updateUser/), but no use.

What am I missing and what is the meaning of "requiring undigested password"?

Comment: What does `version()` report in the `mongo` shell? This should ideally match your server version or at least the release series (4.0.x).

Answer (score 4):

Basically, I made it with [db.updateUser](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.updateUser/#definition).

On the doc, it says the following:

- passwordDigestor : **string**

> Optional. Indicates whether the server or the client digests the password.
>
> Available values are:
>
> "server" (Default)
>           The server receives undigested password from the client and digests the password.
>
> "client" (Not compatible with SCRAM-SHA-256)
>           The client digests the password and passes the digested password to the server.
>
> Changed in version 4.0: The default value is "server". In earlier versions, the default value is "client".

It seems that, the default was "client", by unknown reasons. By the way, my Mongo Shell Client is v3.6.3.

Therefore, I just defined `passwordDigestor` as `server`, and ok. Logged out and logged in with the new password.

```
> db.updateUser("mongo", {pwd:"mongo_n3w_p4ss", passwordDigestor:"server"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the same mongo shell version as the mongo server version solved this issue for me.
I was getting errors for version mismatch 4.0 vs 4.4 as well. it should be exactly the same.
Download the mongo shell/ other packages [here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community)